# Alfresco FTS using TMQ on upgraded machine giving a timeout when using OR

Tags: solr, full-text-search, alfresco

I'm trying to use FTS using TMQs on an upgraded Alfresco (upgraded from 4.0 to 4.2 to 5.1f). However I'll get timeouts when trying to use the OR clause in the queries. I have executed both patches as instructed in the [Alfresco docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/intrans-metadata-conf-patch.html). Using the following code:

```
system.metadata-query-indexes.ignored=false
system.metadata-query-indexes-more.ignored=false
```

When setting the solr.query.fts.queryConsistency to EVENTUAL the queries will work, but then obviously TMQ isn't used.

There are NO errors in the logs, until the FTS query is executed.

I have tried:

1. Reindexing SOLR (during time of testing indexing has completed)
2. Reindexing Postgres DB columns
3. Restarting Alfresco (Time and time again)

This is the query I am using, the node has 7 children and 2 should match the query. Both properties are type d:text.

```
ASPECT:jj\:customAspect AND PARENT:workspace\://SpacesStore/1c96da81-8b4d-4bd7-87f0-f921fd1879c7 AND (=jj:customUserField:admin OR =jj:customGroupField:GROUP_TestGroup )
```

Can anyone help me solve or analyze this problem? I'm really at my wits' end here. I'm suspecting it's a performance issue, there are 1mln docs in this Alfresco. The machine has 8gb ram and currently 1 user on Alfresco.

Comment: Could you post a sample code snippet? Or at least a sample query?

Comment: Thank you @Younes for the comment, I added a query. I also added some specs for the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing some memory settings, I tried adding 8gb more RAM to the server machine. After the RAM was added the FTS TMQ worked again.

If you're having this issue I suggest that you look at the memory settings of all your services and add more memory if necessary.